# How to fix TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have this error message that comes in from time to time that crashes my bot.
Here is the error in the console:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null`

The error comes from this line:

```
description: <@!${msg.member.id}> \nNapotkałem błąd przy twojej rejestracji!\nPowód: Wpisałeś błędny nick!\nWpisz prawidłowy nick!,
```

code

```
      const nznick = {
        color: 0x3a004d,
          title: `Błąd!`, 
          url: '',
          author: {
            name: '',
            icon_url: '',
            url: '',
          },
          description: `<@!${msg.member.id}> \nNapotkałem błąd przy twojej rejestracji!\n**Powód:** Wpisałeś błędny nick!\nWpisz prawidłowy nick!`, // \n to oznacza ze ma od nowej linii zaczac
          thumbnail: {
            url: ``,
          },
          image: {
            url: '',
          },
          footer: {
            text: `RealmApp | 2021`,
            icon_url: '',
          }
        };
```

this is embed and if some one use command bot send this message

Comment: It's so obvious. Did you need to extract that `msg.member.id` value or it's only a json string?

Comment: if the user sends a command
!xyz bot, I take its name and mark it in the reply message

Comment: `Message#member` returns null in a Direct Message since there's no guild

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are in nodejs v14, you Can write :

```js
      const nznick = {
        color: 0x3a004d,
          title: `Błąd!`, 
          url: '',
          author: {
            name: '',
            icon_url: '',
            url: '',
          },
          description: `<@!${msg?.member?.id}> \nNapotkałem błąd przy twojej rejestracji!\n**Powód:** Wpisałeś błędny nick!\nWpisz prawidłowy nick!`, // \n to oznacza ze ma od nowej linii zaczac
          thumbnail: {
            url: ``,
          },
          image: {
            url: '',
          },
          footer: {
            text: `RealmApp | 2021`,
            icon_url: '',
          }
        };
```

Thats send <@undefined> without errors.

If you are in nodejs v12 :
Just use a condition before the object declaration :
if(!msg || !msg.member) return;

Comment: where I can check my nodejs version?```

Comment: Use your console and write : node -v

Comment: version - v10.24.1

Comment: It's like in V10. You can take the v12 options

Comment: Idk, maybe i'm st... ;p ``` if(!msg || !msg.member) return; ``` This work, ty bro ;)